# C++ - parameter question

Tags: c++, boost, parameters, containers

I am looking for some simple and efficient parameter container that would act like a *in-memory-xml* file representation (or *ini-file*, as another sample).

I mean, basically it could store sections and sets of parameters for each section, have easy accessors like `GetValue("ParameterName")` and simple return value casting.

It would be great if it is serializable.

*I wrote something like that yesterday and, well, it suits my needs, but probably there is something more convenient and flexible available?*

Maybe some kind of parameter map in `boost`?

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at [boost::program_options](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/program_options.html). It does what you want and more: INI file parsing, environment variables parsing, commandline options parsing and extensibility.

Answer (score 4):

Have you considered [std::map<>](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/)?

Comment: Right now I am using a wrapper around `boost::unordered_map` which could be easily switched, to `std::map` (still I really enjoy hash-based structures :) But `boost` and other template libraries are actually known for their solutions to any problems, so, I thought that something more convenient may exist...

Comment: Considering he is going to use std::map, I wonder what could be the simplest way to serialize it?

Comment: @Vargas **`boost::serialize`, I suspect.** In my case I had to write custom serialization routine for `boost::unordered_map` and, well, it's not that tough as it seems first :)

Answer (score 2):

Dunno if it's overkill or not, but the [Message class](https://public.msli.com/lcs/muscle/html/classmuscle_1_1Message.html) in MUSCLE does all of the things you listed above.  You can use it to serialize any kind of data (structured or not), or use it as an in-memory container for parsed .ini style config files via [ParseFile()](https://public.msli.com/lcs/muscle/html/group__miscutilityfunctions.html#ga53e933a2aac7a2182c249165d98094d3)/[UnparseFile()](https://public.msli.com/lcs/muscle/html/group__miscutilityfunctions.html#ga3a1a0c0c00f0f0d54c7b9ec32d4c7c54).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Boost.PropertyTree](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/property_tree.html).

It reads and writes xml and ini files.

It stores the parameters as a tree and you can use dot notation to access the values:

```
std::string value = pt.get<std::string>("debug.filename");
```

You can also insert new values using:

```
pt.put("debug.filename", fileName);
```